# Table displaying count of data with conditions AngluarJS

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I am trying to create a table like below:

Number of days   Count
Over 3 days       3
Over 20 days      4
Over 30 days      5

So I get back a total count of things open over 3 days etc. 
Problem 1: If i use Ng-repeat i cannot specify my row titles (i.e column 1)
Problem 2: My data is not pulling through

Please find a snippet of my code below:

My Controller :

```
$scope.requests = requests;

function daysBetween(modifiedDate) {
  var currentDate = new Date();
  modifiedDate = new Date(modifiedDate);
  return UtilityFactory.getNumberOfDaysBetween(currentDate, modifiedDate);
}

 $scope.numberOfDaysSince = function(modifiedDate) {
          var days = daysBetween(modifiedDate);
          if(days === 1) {
            return '(1 day)';
          } else {
            return '(' + days + ' days)';
          }
        };
```

My index.html

```
 <table class="table table-condensed" st-safe-src="requests" st-table="requestsCollection">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Number Of days</th>
                        <th>Total Count</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="request in requestsCollection ">
                    <td>Over 3 days</td>
                    <td>column 2
                    <span ng-repeat="requestCollection in requestsColl| filter: numberOfDaysSince(ticket.Modified) > 3">
                                {{requestsColl.length}}
                            </span>
                                        {{requestsColl.length}}
                                    </span>
                        </td>

                    <td>Over 20 days</td>
                    <td>
                            <span ng-repeat="requestCollection in requestsColl| filter: numberOfDaysSince(ticket.Modified) > 20">
                                {{requestsColl.length}}
                            </span>
                    </td>

                    <td>Over 30 days</td>
                    <td>
                            <span ng-repeat="requestCollection in requestsColl| filter: numberOfDaysSince(ticket.Modified) > 30">
                                {{requestsColl.length}}
                            </span>
                    </td>

                    <td>Total</td>
                    <td>                            
                                {{requestsCollection.length}}
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>

            </table>
```

Comment: Please show an example of your data? `requestsCollection` is undefined going by your code.

Comment: also what are you getting back, what's not working?

Comment: {{requestsCollection}} is returning this in the view:

[{"RequestID":1,"Name":"Anna","StatusID":1,"Status":"Sitting","CreatedDate":"2016-10-28T13:04:16","ModifiedDate":"2016-10-28T14:32:25","DurationAtStatus":2"},[{"RequestID":2,"Name":"Claire","StatusID"21,"Standing":"Sitting","CreatedDate":"2015-10-28T13:04:17","ModifiedDate":"2016-10-28T14:32:25","DurationAtStatus":2569"},[{"RequestID":3,"Name":"Brian","StatusID":1,"Status":"Sitting","CreatedDate":"2016-09-28T13:04:16","ModifiedDate":"2016-10-28T14:32:25","DurationAtStatus":220"},

Comment: Can you create a plunker with sample hard coded data? So that its easier to understand the problem